# Prove (iii) of the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function the best substitute available (Real Analysis, by Stein and Shakarchi)

Tags: real-analysis

If f is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, define the maximal function $f^*$ by:
$$f^*(x)=\sup_{x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B |f(y)|dy,\ x\in \mathbb{R}^d$$
where the supremum is taken over all balls containing the point x.

For any integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, define the norm of $f$ as follows:
$$||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|dx$$

Theorem 1.1 Suppose f is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d.$ Then:

(i) $f^*$ is measurable.

(ii)$f^*(x)<\infty$ for $a.e. x.$

(iii)$f^*$ satisfies
$$(1)\ m(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:f^*(x)>\alpha\})\le \frac{A}{\alpha}||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}$$

for all $\alpha>0,$ where $A=3^d.$

From the book,"As we shall observe, one has that $f*(x)\ge |f(x)|$ for $a.e.x;$ the effect of (iii) is that, broadly speaking, $f*$ is not much larger than $|f|$. From this point of view, we would have liked to conclude that $f*$ is integrable, as a result of the assumed integrability of $f$. However, this is not the case, and (iii) is the best substitute available(See Exercise 4,5)"

4. Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f$ is not identically zero, then $$f^*(x)\ge \frac{c}{|x|^d},\text{for some }c>0\text{ and all }|x|\ge 1.$$
   Conclude that $f*$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d.$ Then, show that the weak type  estimate $$m(\{ x: f^*(x)>\alpha\})\le \frac{c}{\alpha}$$
   for all $\alpha>0$ whenever $\int |f|=1,$ is best possible in the following sense: if $f$ is supported in the unit ball with $\int |f|=1,$ then
   $$m(\{ x:f^*(x)>\alpha\})\ge \frac{c'}{\alpha}$$
   for some $c'>0$ and all sufficiently small $\alpha.$

[Hint: For the first part, use the fact that $\int_{B}|f|>0$ for some ball $B$]

5.Consider the function on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{|x|(\log{\frac{1}{|x|}})^2},  & \text{if $|x|\le\frac{1}{2}$,} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

(a) Verify that $f$ is integrable.
(b) Establish the inequality
$$f^*(x)\ge \frac{c}{|x|(\log{1/|x|})^2,} \text{ for some $c>0$ and all $|x|\le1/2$,}$$
to conclude that the maximal function $f^*$ is not locally integrable.

I prove the first and second parts of 4 using the hint and (iii), but I don't know how to get the third part.
For 5(a) I used $$\int_{|x|<\epsilon}\frac{dx}{|x|^a}=\epsilon^{-a+d}\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{dx}{|x|^a}, \text{ whenever $a<d$}.$$
$\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{dx}{|x|^a}$ is finite(already proven).

But I have no idea how to establish the inequality of 5(b).

Comment: 5b follows from $f^{*}(x) \geq |f(x)|$ a.e.

Comment: Just thinking for 5b, assuming the inequality holds as written, we don't conclude that $f*$ is not integrable. However using the first part of 4, it is easy to establish that $f^*$ is not locally integrable

Comment: please correct $f*$ to $f^*.$

Comment: Please label $4 a, 4 b, 5b$ appropriately.

Comment: thank you for reminding, I changed it